# check valid date in java

Tags: java, date

I tried to check a `String` input that is a valid date using the format `dd/MM/yyyy` like this:

```
String input = Scanner.nextLine();
DateTimeFormatter formater = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
try{
    LocaleDate.parse(input, formater);
}
catch(Exception e)
```

But it can't check some rules below:

```
Leap year, February 29 days.

Common year, February 28 days.

Month 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, max 31 days.

Month 4, 6, 9, 11, max 30 days.
```

When I use `input = "30/02/2022"`, it's legal.
I use `netbeans 8.2` and `jdk 1.8`. Do they support some methods for checking these rules?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two things you need to change in your formatter:

- Use `uuuu` instead of `yyyy`. It's easy to try the latter, but `y` means "year within ERA". It doesn't know whether it's BC or AD. `u` means "year" including ERA information.
- The [default resolver style](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String)) is [`SMART`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART). Use `.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)` to return a [strict](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT) copy of the formatter.

Comment: not only "Apparently", the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String)) clearly states: *"It uses [SMART](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART) resolver style."*

Comment: Yes, I saw that, I just wasn't aware of that yet myself.

Comment: To summary: the `uuuu` here to check the ERA, so it help to check if the year are leap year or not. And the `.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT)` to check `Month 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, max 31 days. Month 4, 6, 9, 11, max 30 days.`. And the `SMART` just check if moth within 1 and 12 and day within 1 and 31. am i right ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the strict mode of the DateTimeFormatter :

```
DateTimeFormatter formater = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")
                            .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
```

`LocaleDate.parse("30/02/2022, formater);` will then throw an exception.

Comment: As I said below, you need to use `uuuu` instead of `yyyy`, otherwise you'll get other exceptions.

Comment: Strictly speaking true, and the thought is correct, but it’s not enough. It throws `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '30/02/2022' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=30, MonthOfYear=2, YearOfEra=2022},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed`. But if I use `28/02/2022` instead, it throws a very similar exception, so we can’t use it for distinguishing valid and invalid dates as it stands.

Comment: @OleV.V. that's what the `uuuu` fixes. That uses field `Year` and not `YearOfEra`, and therefore the 2022 is 2022 AD instead of 2022 (don't know if AD or BC).